# How to rebuild the set of installed packages when you have a broken install on Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, dpkg

On Ubuntu 19.10, I have a broken install/removal of MariaDB.  I attempted every solution to this sort of problem.  Yet I still can't replace MariaDB with mysql-server and am seemingly unable to remove MariaDB.

What is left on the system in /var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb* that I want to go away is:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  118 Oct 27 14:02 mariadb-client-10.3.list
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  174 Aug  2 10:53 mariadb-client-10.3.postrm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   28 Oct 27 14:02 mariadb-common.list
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  361 Aug  2 10:53 mariadb-common.postrm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  509 Oct 27 14:02 mariadb-server-10.3.list
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3449 Aug  2 10:53 mariadb-server-10.3.postrm
```

Yet when I try anything like:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mariadb (or variations)
```

gives only:

```
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove mariadb-server which isn't installed
```

SO how do I rebuild the database of installed packages??? and create a health system again??

Comment: Possibly I would be better to ask on askubuntu

Comment: I will try that. But this such a common problem, I was hoping that someone here might know.  Maybe someone will chime in later.